# BackstopJs. Am I able to use a png or svg as the reference URL?

Tags: backstop.js

I am currently learning BackstopJs for visual regression testing. However, our files for the reference are based in figma and are difficult to grab the exact screen I need (we show several views in one file). Is there a way for me to use a png as the referenceUrl?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that I could just link to the file in the URL of the browser and backstop works great with it.

ex: File /Users/user/Desktop/image